# Processing: Extract only decimals of a float as float

Tags: math, floating-point, processing

I need to know the decimals of a float, a function that takes a float like

```
float in1 = 2013.45
float in2 = 367.678
```

and results in a

```
float out1 = 0.45
float out2 = 0.678
```

I have seen the built-in [nf()](http://processing.org/reference/nf_.html) but it returns a String. What would be the most elegant/convenient way of achieving this?

Edit: I have tried

```
float in = 2013.45;
float out = in-floor(in);
```

but the result is 0.44995117 instead of 0.45.

Comment: If processing has a floor function, then `x-floor(x)` (for positive x).

Comment: Hi I tried this, but it gives me not accurate outputs.

Comment: You are seeing the limitations of representing decimal values in binary. [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) Does processing have a decimal data type you could use instead of float?

Comment: Do you mean something like long? http://processing.org/reference/long.html

Comment: Ah, no. `long` is an integer data type. You may be stuck with working with strings, or the `double` type might give more acceptable results.

Comment: Thanks for that. I have tried now double out3= in - floor(in); but get an error The method floor(float) in the type PApplet is not applicable for the arguments(double). So no flooring on doubles in Processing or am I missing the point?

Comment: In mathematics, this is called the "fractional part" of the number.

Comment: For doubles, use java's function, not processing's: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor%28double%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

positive `in`:

```
out = in - (float) floor(in)
```

negative `in`:

```
out = in - (float) ceil(in)
```

Comment: Does processing not have a `ceiling` to complement `floor`?

Comment: @BjørnBråthen So, `out = in - (float) ceil(in)` for in < 0, surely?

Answer (score 3):

> Edit: I have tried
>
> ```
> float in = 2013.45;
> float out = in-floor(in);
> ```
>
> but the result is 0.44995117 instead of 0.45.

**That can be correct. What you see here is [loss of precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance).**

For the sake of simplicity, first let's pretend that the computer works in base 10 (in other words, in decimal numeral system).

[A 32 bit float has 7 correct significant decimal digits.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Internal_representation) 2013.45 is represented as 2013.450 internally. Now, when you substract the integer part, 4 of the significant digits become zero:

```
   2013.450
 - 2013
 ----------
       .450
```

In other words, **4 significant digits are lost, the result is only accurate up to 3 significant digits. You would need more digits of the *input* 2013.450 to achieve a more precise result.**  Unfortunately, you are limited to 7 digits with a 32 bit float and there is nothing you can do about it.

What happens next in floating point computations is that (made up) zeros are appended to the result until we have 7 significant digits again. It is called normalization. In base 10 we would be *accidentally* lucky as the correct digits happen to be 0 (most likely to be the reason for your confusion) but the computer works in base 2. This code shows how the actual computations are carried out internally, in hexadecimal format and in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  float       x = 2013.45;
  float floor_x = 2013;
  float       y = x - floor_x;

  printf("      x  = %a\n", x);
  printf("floor(x) = %.6a\n", floor_x);
  printf("      y  = %.6a\n", y);
}
```

It prints:

```
       x  = 0x1.f75cccp+10 
 floor(x) = 0x1.f74000p+10
       y  = 0x1.ccc000p-2
```

As you can see, `y` was renormalized by appending three `0`s at the back. However, the correct digits would have been `c` in base 16. **We would have been lucky in base 10 only by sheer accident as in base 10 the appended zeros and the true digits would have coincided.**

---

One more note. **The printing function can make up garbage digits.** The computer works in base 2 internally but the result is printed in base 10 so a conversion from base 2 to base 10 is needed. Even though you can print a floating point number up to any number of digits, it won't make it more accurate than its internal accuracy. Demonstration in C, printing `1.1` up to 15 digits:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  float x = 1.1;
  printf("x = %.15f\n", x);
}
```

This program prints

```
x = 1.100000023841858
```

on my machine. As a float has 7 significant digits, everything after the 7th digit should be regarded as garbage. As you can see, it *is* garbage.

After you have computed `float out = in-floor(in);` in your example and have lost 4 out of the 7 digits, you should only print the result up to 3 digits and it is your responsibility to do so. Up to 3 significant digits 0.44995117 *is* 0.450 which is what you were expecting.

Comment: I wish this answer made it clearer that the computation of `out`, as written, is exact. The digits `44995117` were there all along. More specifically, `2013.45` is represented in binary32 format exactly as `2013.449951171875`. The computation `in-floor(in)` computes exactly `0.449951171875`. It is only the printing function that gives the impression that something else is happening.

Comment: I confirm that when one assigns `2013.45` to a `float` variable, the float variable ends up containing `0x1.f75cccp+10` which is exactly `2013.449951171875`. The notion of significant digits you are trying to rely on is confusing you.

Comment: @PascalCuoq OK, then I probably don't understand the point that you make in your first comment. As I read it, it is saying that `in-floor(in)` is *exactly* `0.449951171875`. My claim is that it is 0.450 and everything else after the third digit is just garbage and should be ignored. If you like, my claim is that the result is within the interval `[0.445,0.455)`, that is what I can trust. If something is *exactly* 0.449951171875, then I can trust all of its digits (which I cannot, starting from the 3rd). Anyway, if you are satisfied with the updated answer, let's leave it at that.

Answer (score 2):

Surely it is better to simply use `out = in % 1;`, which works for positive or negative `in`.